# Diffing a file against last Mercurial changeset, should it be different?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, diff

I'm seeing something I don't expect in my Mercurial repo.  A change that has been made in a branch is showing up in default.  There is no changeset in the log, merge or otherwise, accounting for the change moving into default from the branch.

I checked the basics: I'm in default, did an 'hg pull', 'hg update -C', 'hg purge', and an 'hg st' which came back clean.

If I look at the file locally the change I am expecting is not there.  If I do an 'hg diff -r  ' then it tells me that my local file is missing the change I expect to see.  The file does not show as modified in 'hg st' and a simple 'hg diff' on it shows no differences.

I would expect that whenever doing a diff with an unmodified file explicity against the last changeset in whatever branch I'm in with '-r' it should come back with no differences.  Am I wrong?  Am I misunderstanding this basic concept?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: I read your question three times and don't really understand what you're talking about. Are you seeing a change you should not or is the change missing where it should be ? Maybe some kind of visual representation (diagram) or at least an example would clarify everything.

Comment: Sorry, this is tough to describe.The last changeset for the default has the change I expect to see and want. The file currently in the filesystem does not reflect the change from the last changeset.  I since there are no later changesets for the file in that branch I don't understand how this can be.  It may be related to a merge.  We just did a merge from the branch to default.  The editor popped open and showed about 30 modified files.  After the commit, an 'hg -v log' on that commit show only about 8 files.  Do merge changesets not show all the affected files?

Comment: Please write to mercurial@selenic.com instead — your question needs a lot of explanation and you need to show the output of things like `hg summary`, `hg status`, and `hg diff`. (The real output, not just your description of the output.) Then we can discuss things further there. This site is for concrete questions, and I feel your question needs more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think hg has an internal cache of which files it thinks are modified, and somehow this has got out of sync. This happened to me before, but I can't remember whether I deleted the file first or just used hg revert.

Comment: I don't think that's it, I think a local cache like that would only be on one computer.  This repo is getting pulled by lots of different people and I can see the same inconsistencies on anyone's computer.